# Including Django-Tagulous tags in a Q Search

Tags: django, tagging

I have a blog style Django app and have implemented Django-Tagulous to manage tags.

I have a Post model with standard fields like Title and Content and I also have a tags field

```
tags = tagulous.models.TagField()
```

When I create a Post the tags are working and saving correctly, I'm now starting to work on search functionality and have the following in my post_list view

```
queryset_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query)|
        Q(content__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
```

I'd really like to include the associated tags but can't get my head round how to do it.
Does anyone have any pointers how to include tags in searches?
I'd really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is covered in the [`README` on GitHub](https://github.com/radiac/django-tagulous). Behind the curtains, the `TagField` is a `ManyToManyField` that points to a model [**`TagModel`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/radiac/django-tagulous/blob/2695c02c8beda4948fb38075d2baee21959810ad/tagulous/models/models.py#L512), and we can thus query the many-to-many relation, like:

```
queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=query) |
    Q(content__icontains=query) |
    Q(tags__name=query)
).distinct()
```

Here we thus filter that there is a tag with a `name` that is exactly the query. But we can add the [**`__iexact`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact), [**`__contains`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or, [**`__icontains`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) lookup, to make searching more sophisticated. For example:

```
queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=query) |
    Q(content__icontains=query) |
    Q(tags__name__icontains=query)
).distinct()
```

will match all objects for which there is a tag where the name contains a substring that is, ignoring the case, equal to the thing we query. So if you tagged something with `'foobar'`, then it will match with a query `'Oo'` as well.